# How to get all cases from Salesforce desk using api?

Tags: salesforce

I'm quite new to Salesforce. I want to export all the data in "All Cases" to excel. I know how to to do with tools in Salesforce but have no idea on how to do this code behind API.Can anyone help me out with a sample code.

Comment: Do you want to do it directly from Excel against the API, or do you want to use an intermediate to extract the required data for use in Excel? You could extract the data to CSV using Apex and Visualforce, or you could use one of several APIs (REST, SOAP, Bulk) to extract the data.